# Как использовать библиотеки, в GHC?

Tags: dll, haskell, lib

У меня не получилось скачать lib'ы через *stack install*, ну или *cabal install* (только через *git* с hackage), а следовательно и скомпилить их, но у меня есть GHC.
Но мне не совсем понятно, «желательно ли эти lib'ы компилить до указания компилятору (и как, собсно), желательно ли эти пакеты помещать в GHC (или достаточно через консоль указать), а если через консоль, то именно как» — Короче, ка́к динамически, и статически…

В общем, задача [предельно простая](https://lokathor.gitbooks.io/using-haskell/content/opengl/).
Есть ещё раздел [API](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html), посвящённый этому, но я не настолько просвещён в этом вопросе.
Мне известно, что в *Haskell Platform* есть предустановленные пакеты, но как их изменить, мне неизвестно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот каскадно вызываемый вопрос, изжился сам собой, путём установки [необходимых](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96087/how-to-install-opengl-glut-libraries) библиотек, и ожидаемой подсказкой у cabal:

```
cabal install --lib OpenGL
```

Спасибо за наводку у сайта *antona kholomiova*
Правда, я всё ещё до конца не понимаю, как управлять библиотекой пакетов, и их корневыми зависимостями…

Answer (score 0):

Но если у вас cabal, при установке пакетов выводит «таблицу ошибок», или свой «трёхстрочный приговор» вашим усердиям, то у меня [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749961/cabal-trouble-resolving-dependencies) постоянное решение.